# New FB Comments export to a db

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i went through alot of posts here to see how to export all the comments left on a website from the fb comments social plug in (wordpress site even though doesnt really matter). But I still can't find a clear answer. Is there a definitive answer or try/error? Apparently FQL using xids doesn't work anymore because facebook is using urls now. I know you can go link by link to export them but I am looking for something more automated. I wonder if this will still work http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7389950/export-comments-from-fbcomments/7462589#7462589

any ideas / help / direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it, at the time of the post...

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function (response) {
    var commentQuery = FB.Data.query('SELECT fromid, text FROM comment WHERE post_fbid=\'' + response.commentID + '\' AND object_id IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url=\'' + response.href + '\')');

    FB.Data.waitOn([commentQuery], function () {
        text = commentQuery.value[0].text;
        fromid = commentQuery.value[0].fromid;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", // form method
            url: "add_fb_comments.php", // destination
            data: "&fromid=" + fromid + "&comment=" + text + "&commentID=" + response.commentID, // data to post
            cache: false
        });
    });
});
```

Then in `add_fb_comments.php`, simply save the details posted there.